# Laravel игнорирует метод в контроллере

Tags: laravel, controller, php, маршрутизация

Есть контроллер:

```
class HomeController extends BaseController {
    public function index() {
        return View::make('hello');
    }
}
```

и при наличии роута:

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');
```

появляется ошибка:

```
BadMethodCallException 
Method [index] does not exist.
```

Команда `php artisan routes`, возвращает то что нужно:

```
+--------+------------+------+----------------------+----------------+---------------+
| Domain | URI        | Name | Action               | Before Filters | After Filters |
+--------+------------+------+----------------------+----------------+---------------+
|        | GET|HEAD / |      | HomeController@index |                |               |
+--------+------------+------+----------------------+----------------+---------------+
```

Версия: `Laravel 4.2.11`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решена. Вся проблема была в том что в папке `vendor/laravel` находилась папка laravel полностью дублирующая корневую директорию из-за этого пространства имен спутались и поиск был не в корневой директории а в папке `vendor`.

Пригодится кому-нибудь на будущее. :)

Answer (score 1):

А в HomeController у Вас, видимо, дефолтный метод остался, да?

Попробуйте роут прописать как-нибудь так:

```
Route::get('/', ['as' => 'home', 'uses' => 'HomeController@showWelcome']);
```

Ещё может быть косяк с автолоадингом. Попробуйте:

- удалить папку vendor
- удалить файл bootstrap/compiled.php
- запустите composer update